# Do not display the last post on the archive page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I need the last post not to be displayed on the post archive page.

What should I do to do this?

You can see the page code of my page archive below.

```
<?php
    /* Start the Loop */
    $i=0;
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        if($i==5) {
            echo '
                adv code
            ';
        }
        the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'archive' );

    $i++;
    endwhile;

    custom_pagination();

    else :

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif;
?>
```

note: Only the last post. Because the last post of the page archive is displayed manually in the slider of that page. I do not want the last post in the list to be displayed and repeated.

Comment: your results seem to be paginated: when you say "last post", you mean the last post on each page, or only the very last post - the last post of the last page?

Comment: @GrafiCode Only the last post. Because the last post of the page archive is displayed manually in the slider of that page. I do not want the last post in the list to be displayed and repeated.

Comment: oh, I think I see: you mean the "latest" post, which is the very first post displayed in the archive page?

Comment: @GrafiCode Yes, exactly :D

Comment: please have a look at this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination#Offset_Using_pre_get_posts there's a specific example showing hot to set a hook to specify an `offset` for your query results (which is exactly what you need, to exclude the latest post from the loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using offset to the query will do the trick like

```
function exclude_last_post( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_archive() ) {
        $query->set( 'offset', '1' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_last_post' );
```